# Event to be fired only when outer li is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want an event to be fired when the `li` of outer list is clicked. I've written a function for it but the event is being fired even when I click the inner list `li`. Please help.

I have the following HTML structure :

```
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" id="outer-menu">
     <li id="R1"><a href="#">Sample Reports</a>
          <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" id="inner-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Employee salary report</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Car sales Report</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Business client report</a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
    </ul>
```

And jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#outer-menu a').on('click',function(){
        alert("this clicked");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following for restricting the matched set to direct children only:

```
$('#outer-menu > li > a').on('click',function() {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
$('#outer-menu li a').on('click',function(){
    alert("this clicked");
});
```

Or even try like

```
$('#outer-menu #R1 a').on('click',function(){
    alert("this clicked");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to target only the direct childrens, and you can also stop event propagation/bubbling(here you used a alert on click event, but if you use an animation later, you will need to stop the animation propagation), so you can use the following code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#outer-menu > li > a').on('click',function(){
        alert("this clicked");
      }).stop(true, true);
    });
```